# Finding a homomorphism for groups of same exponent

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $B$ be a finite abelian group of exponent dividing m (the smallest integer $r$ with $r/m$ and $b^r=e \;\forall b\in B$). Pick a $b\in B$. Then we can find a 
$c\in\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ with $\operatorname{ord}(b)=\operatorname{ord}(c)$. Is there a homomomorphism $h:B\to\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ with $h(b)=c$?

Tried some thing with the fundamental theorem for abelian groups, but couldn't construct an explicit homomorphism with this property.

Comment: The problem is ill-posed, in my opinion: if you choose $c_0$ for some $b$ and the same $c_0$ for $b^{-1}$, then of course not as soon as the order of $b$ is $>2$.

Comment: Your right, will edit it. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you want to find $h\colon B\to\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ so that, for each $b\in B$, $\operatorname{ord}(b)=\operatorname{ord}(h(b))$. Or is the element $b$ fixed?

Comment: Edited it. The element b is fixed.

Comment: Your question, as written right now, asks whether taking one element $b$ from an abelian group $B$ and,given $m = \operatorname{exp}(B) \times k$ for any $k$, an element $c$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(m)$ with the same order as $b$, you can construct a homomorphism from $B$ to $\mathbb{Z}/(m)$ that maps $b$ to $c$.
I suspect that you are actually asking if you can embed $B$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(m)$ making sure that $b$ is mapped to $c$, so your homomorphism would need to be injective. Is that the case?

Comment: nope, the homomorphism doesn't need to be injective. Our $B$ can be much larger than $\mathbb{Z}/(m)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. We start with $B$ cyclic of prime power order, then prime power order in general, then the general case. We may clearly assume that $m$ is the exponent of $B$.

**cyclic prime power order**

If $B$ is cyclic of prime power order then $B\cong\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, and $m=p^t$ for some prime $p$ and integer $t$. Fix a generator $g$ of $B$. It suffices to do the following:

> For any $x\in B$ of order $p^s$ find an automorphism mapping $g^{p^{t-s}}$ to $x$.

This is sufficient as we may map $b\mapsto g^{p^{t-s}}\mapsto c$ for the appropriate choice of $s$.

Clearly any element can be written in the form $x=g^{x_0+x_1p+\cdots x_{t-1}p^{t-1}}$ with $x_i\in\{0,\ldots,p-1\}$ for each $i$ - we keep this notation, so for example $b=g^{b_0+b_1p+\cdots b_{t-1}p^{t-1}}$. For $x\ne 1$ let $l(x)$ be minimal such that $x_{l(x)}\ne 0$ - notably ${\rm ord}(x)=p^{t-l(x)}$. It will be convenient to choose $l(1)=t$.

For fixed $x$ consider the isomorphism $h:g\mapsto g^{x_{l(x)}+px_{l(x)+1}+\cdots+p^{t-l(x)-1}x_{t-1}}$ so $h(g^{p^{l(x)}})=x$ and we are done.

**prime power order**

Write $B=\mathbb{Z}/p^{e_1}\mathbb{Z}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}/p^{e_t}\mathbb{Z}$ for some prime $p$ and integers $e_1\le\ldots\le e_t$ and let $f_i:B\to\mathbb{Z}/p^{e_i}\mathbb{Z}$ be the natural projection map for each $i$. Clearly $m=p^{e_t}$ and ${\rm ord}(b)=\max({\rm ord}(f_i(b)))$ so we may fix $s$ such that ${\rm ord}(b)={\rm ord}(f_s(b))$. We also fix $g_i\in B$ which generates $\mathbb{Z}/p^{e_i}\mathbb{Z}$ for each $i$.

Let $h_0:\mathbb{Z}/p^{e_s}\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p^{e_t}\mathbb{Z}$ be the injective homomorphism taking $\overline 1$ to $\overline{p^{e_t-e_s}}$. By the cyclic prime power order case there is some $h_1:\mathbb{Z}/p^{e_t}\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p^{e_t}\mathbb{Z}$ with $h_1(h_0(f_s(b)))=c$. Now, let $h:B\to\mathbb{Z}/p^{e_t}\mathbb{Z}$ be the homomorphism with $h(g_i)=\overline{0}$ for $i\ne s$ and $h(g_s)=h_1(h_0(f_s(g_s)))$, then $h(b)=c$.

**general case**

It is an immediate (depending on the precise statement) corollary of the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups, that we may write $B=P_1\times\cdots\times P_t$ where the $P_i$ have pairwise coprime orders and each $P_i$ is of prime power order. Denote $b=(b_1,\ldots,b_t)$.

It is also straightforward to show that if $m_i$ is the exponent of $P_i$ for each $i$ then the $m_i$ are pairwise coprime and $m=m_1m_2\cdots m_t$. In particular $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}/m_1\mathbb{Z}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}/m_t\mathbb{Z}$ so we may denote $c=(c_1,\ldots,c_t)$.

By the prime power order case, there is a homomorphism $h_i:P_i\to\mathbb{Z}/m_i\mathbb{Z}$ with $h_i(b_i)=c_i$ for each $i$, so the proof is complete by taking $h=h_1\times\cdots\times h_t$.

Comment: I guess we can assume that $m$ is the exponent of B, since otherwise it only requires a little modification of your cyclic prime power order case? The argumentation in the other two cases should stay the same.

Comment: Justifying it out loud, I was perhaps hasty to say it's clear. If the exponent $e$ divides $m$ then $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ has a unique subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/e\mathbb{Z}$ and any element of order ${\rm ord}(b)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is in $\mathbb{Z}/e\mathbb{Z}$ because it generates the unique subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ of order ${\rm ord }(b)$ and $\mathbb{Z}/e\mathbb{Z}$ contains such a subgroup. So we map into $\mathbb{Z}/e\mathbb{Z}$ which embeds into $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.